# How to add a generic type to a enumerable

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do something like this

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; private set; }
public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

public void Add<T>(T item)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo))
        Foos.Append<Foo>(item);

    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar))
        Bars.Append<Bar>(item);
}
```

Am I crazy, or is this possible?

Comment: Should be possible, I guess. I don't think you need the generic for the Append method. And you also need to handle if someone doesn't send Foo or Bar.

Comment: My main question is why?

Comment: You know there is the method Concat? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0

Comment: Since you want to `Add` why not use a collection that actually supports adding items to it like `List<T>` ?

Comment: it is possible somehow, see answer below. But what's the point? what about having 2 method `addFoo(...)` and `addBar()`? the calling code should know if it's handling a Foo or a Bar instance, and call the right method. Also, compiler will help you in spotting errors: what if you pass a string to your generic method? that's the kind of bug compiler can spot for you before runtime;

Comment: The main issue is that you're throwing the new `IEnumerable` that `Append` returns away.  You'd need to do `Foos = Foos.Append(item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; private set; }
public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

public void Add<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo))
        Foos.Append((T)item);

    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar))
        Bars.Append((T)item);
}
```

But this is not type-safe what I assume is what you are aiming for. In particular, the check that `typeof(T) == typeof(Foo)` is essentially ignored by the compiler. Also, that will only work if you add the `: class` constraint. Otherwise, you have to convert to `object` first.

P.S.: Side topic, `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an append and extension methods will not modify the collection, so calling `Append` is probably pointless.

P.P.S.: Thinking more about it, I guess the statement that the compiler ignores the check is incorrect or at least up to the implementation of the JIT compiler. To my knowledge, however, the JIT compiler will only generate one implementation for all reference types and hence perform the type check at runtime and my comment still stands.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this solution:

```
public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; private set; }
public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

public void Add<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo))
        Foos.Add(item as Foo);      

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar))
        Bars.Add(item as Bar);
}
```

You can use C# lists for working with multiple elements. Usage will be something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Foos = new List<Foo>();
Bars = new List<Bar>();

var item1 = new Foo();
var item2 = new Foo();
var item3 = new Bar();
    
Add(item1);     
Add(item2);
Add(item3);

// Output length of lists or their content to check the result
```

P.S. If those collections and methods remain non-static object creating should be included firstly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a common ancestor interface and store the data in one list

```
public interface IData
{
}
public class Bar : IData
{
}

public class Foo : IData
{
}

public class Storage
{
    readonly List<IData> Data;

    public Storage()
    {
        this.Data = new List<IData>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get => Data.OfType<Foo>(); }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get => Data.OfType<Bar>(); }


    public void Add<T>(T item) where T: class, IData
    {
        Data.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use two separate lists for the two types, use pattern matching in `Add()`

```
public class Bar 
{
}

public class Foo 
{
}

public class Storage
{
    readonly List<Foo> foos;
    readonly List<Bar> bars;

    public Storage()
    {
        foos = new List<Foo>();
        bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get => foos; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get => bars; }


    public void Add<T>(T item) where T: class
    {
        if (item is Foo foo)
        {
            foos.Add(foo);
        }
        if (item is Bar bar)
        {
            bars.Add(bar);
        }
    }
}
```